# Leomund's Tiny Hut -- only the caster can't exit and enter at will?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The text for *Leomund's tiny hut* says in part:

> Creatures and objects within the dome when you cast this spell can
>   move through it freely.

but also

> The spell ends if you leave its area.

I read that as saying that everyone can exit and enter at will, except the caster, who must remain inside the hut for the entire time.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes you are correct

> A 10-foot-radius immobile dome of force springs into existence around
>   and above you and remains stationary for the duration. The spell ends
>   if you leave its area.

This paragraph solely focuses on what happens when the spell is cast including when it ends. The dome ends after 8 hours or when you leave it.

> Nine creatures of Medium size or smaller can fit inside the dome with
>   you. The spell fails if its area includes a larger creature or more
>   than nine creatures. Creatures and objects within the dome when you
>   cast this spell can move through it freely....

This paragraph (and the omitted part) references what happens to the things and creatures inside the dome.

Answer (score 2):

The differences between this and the D20 "Tiny Hut" are informative: http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/tinyHut.htm

The D20 version explicitly states "However, if you remove yourself from the hut, the spell ends." - 5E's wording is far less clear, but I would interpret it to mean the same thing: being able to see the evolution of the spell description in this way makes the intent of the designers obvious, even when their words are less than clear in the final product.

This is also useful for tackling the question of what happens when the ground isn't perfectly flat, or if the caster is casting it at the top of a pillar, or upstairs in an inn: the D20 rules explicitly state that it's a sphere, but only a dome is normally visible, which makes intellectual sense. This also precludes abuse by casting it on a cart, for example, as the buried part could not move through the earth.

This "see how the spell evolved over time" idea obviously can't be applied universally, though: the 5E rules must still be considered canon, in a 5E campaign, and all the D20 rules can do is give a suggestion at what the intent of the designers might have been, in grey areas like this.

For example, the D20 version is far less exploitable by savvy players: it is not invincible against incursion by foes or magic: it merely provides cover and shelter, and can be destroyed if trampled by a mob. Personally, I feel this is in the spirit of the spell, as being intended to provide a simple tent like level of protection, rather than an invincible shield/gun-turret/lava-cooling-device/etc. But whatever my feelings, the 5E rules are the rules: which means, the GM needs to handle the fact that the players have the potential for an invulnerable 20ft dome of invulnerability at low level, and if cast as a rune, they can even erect it instantly: http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?358657